# How to query next conversation sort by newest activity?

Tags: sql, mongodb, chat, message

I'm implementing a chat system like Facebook, I have two tables, one is messages and one is conversations:

```
conversations
id  |  peoples         | updatedAt
1      [user1, user2]    Today 8:10 PM 
2      [user1, user2]    Today 9:03 PM
3      [user1, user2]    Today 5:01 PM
4      [user1, user2]    Today 5:01 PM
5      [user1, user2]    Today 5:01 PM
6      [user1, user2]    Today 4:01 PM
```

When a user sent a message, I update the field `updatedAt` of `conversations` by current time so I can query the lastest conversations, but the problem here is how I continue to query the latest conversation after that? For example, first I will query two latest conversation, as you can see here is a conversation with id `2 and 1` will return, then I save the `updatedAt` value of id `1`(the value is `Today 8:10 PM`  ) so I can continue query latest conversation with the condition `{updatedAt: {$lte: Today 8:10 PM}` and take only 2 conversations like first and it will return conversation with id `3,4` and I save the `updatedAt` field of id `4` (value is `Today 5:01 PM`), continue query with same condition: `{updatedAt: {$lte: Today 5:01 PM}` it will return conversation with id `3,5`, the id `3` I have query before I don't need it, so how to avoid this? I use mongodb as database

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to keep `updatedAt` as timestamp.
Mongodb has appropriate type for it. You can see more at docs by
this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

Comment: I define conversation Schema like this
`const schema = new Schema ( { peoples: [ {type:ObjectId } ] }, {timestamp: true})`
the second parameter `{timestamp: true}` add two field `createdAt` `and updatedAt`, is this two field is timestamp type?

Comment: Ah no, from the document `By default, Mongoose uses new Date() to get the current time` I think will gonna change this as a timestamp value, but this timestamp can be converted to normal day so I can display in a view? like `24-2-2020 `